# substract one millisecond to the given Date in Java

Tags: java, milliseconds, java.util.date

i have a Date field ***expiryDate*** with value **Thu Nov 21 00:00:00 IST 2019** But i am trying to get the endDate time to the before to the day by removing a millisecond from the time as **Thu Nov 20 23:59:59 IST 2019**
do we have any methods to remove a millisecond from the given Date.

Comment: `Date b = new Date(a.getTime()-1);`

Comment: Why are you using `Date`?

Comment: Maybe because it is explicitly contained as tag in the question. Maybe OP has some requirement on it. If not, consider moving to `java.time`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *java.time*

Avoid the terrible date-time classes that are now legacy as of JSR 310. Now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

You can easily convert back and forth. Call new conversion methods addd to the old classes.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

And back again.

```
java.util.Date myJavaUtilDate = Date.from( instant ) ;
```

Subtract a millisecond.

```
Instant oneMilliEarlier = instant.minusMillis( 1 ) ;
```

## Half-Open

But I suggest you not take this approach. Do not track a span of time by its last moment.

Your attempt to track the last moment of the day is problematic. You are losing that last millisecond of time. Doing so leaves a gap until the first moment of the next day. And when switching to a finer time slicing such as microseconds used by some systems such as databases like Postgres, and the nanoseconds used by other software such as the *java.time* classes, you have a worse problem.

A better approach is the Half-Open approach commonly used in date-time handling. The beginning of a span-of-time is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

So an entire day starts at the first moment of the day, typically at 00:00:00 (but not always!), and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *next* day.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime start = zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime stop = start.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Tip: For working with such spans of time, add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to access the `Interval` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

yes. i just tried with the above mehtod getTime() returns milliseconds to the given date.
 and substracting a millisecond is giving me a correct output.
new Date(milliseconds) giving me the Date format.

Thanks @Elliott Frisch

Comment: Why are you using `Date`? There is almost no valid reason to use the old bad legacy date api of Java. Consider using `LocalDate` and similar classes of the modern api.

Comment: @Zabuza Lots of valid reasons to use `Date`, e.g. working with any of the many APIs / libraries that use `Date`, including many of the APIs in the Java Runtime Library.

Comment: Yes, that is the *almost no* I mentioned. I'd argue its better to use non-Date as long as possible in your own code and then convert to it when you actually have to provide it to old APIs. Anyways, I will just leave it as note.